# How do I install ionicons in my Ionic 2 project

Tags: ionic2, ionicons

When I try to do  (for example)

```
<ion-icon name="university"></ion-icon>
```

I see that the icon doesn't appear, though its been listed at the http://ionicons.com/. I think may be the icons with my project are not updated one, so I thought to download the package from the site and install.

After unzipping I have no idea about how to do it. I tried the suggestion in the [forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-icons-not-showing/15207), but there it was suggested to go to 'lib' folder in 'www' directory. But, in my project I don't see any 'lib' directory. I tried with the instructions at the [repo site](https://github.com/driftyco/ionicons) , but its again confusing in my case (I think).

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue today. 
I realized some Ionic 2 [Icons](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/ionicons/) have been renamed. 
For example, in your case :

```
<ion-icon name="university"></ion-icon>
```

Becomes:

```
<ion-icon name="school"></ion-icon>
```

I would advise anyone else facing the same issue to carefully look through the new Ionic 2 icons.

Comment: Omg, finally. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you [start you Ionic 2 project with pre-generated content,](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/tutorial/) not as blank, Ionicons should be working from the begining.

The only trick is that icon **names stated at Ionicons.com are NOT** the same as in Ionic 2 documentation, for example:

[image: Ionicon settings]
Settings icon:

in Ionicons: *ion-android-settings*

in Ionic 2 documentation: *md-settings*

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the ionicons from the site and then unzip it and then move the contents of the scss folder inside your project directory. Then you have to just import them into your app.core.scss file in your project's theme directory.

Have a look at http://tphangout.com/?p=199 (Simple instructions are given there).

Comment: No, still I am not getting the icon which I was trying to get - ion-university. I did as per the instruction, did ionic build, ionic serve, but nothing helped... I used like this in html - <ion-icon name="university"></ion-icon>, and when I inspected it was converted to - 
<ion-icon name="university" role="img" class="ion-ios-university" aria-label="university"></ion-icon>

Comment: same issue here :(

Comment: The solution you are linking to does not work anymore